# SQL Case expression issue in the result dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

```
SELECT  
    b.Product_Code,
    b.Account_Id,
    b.Channel_Desc,
    r.Min_Range, r.Max_Range,
    b.Balance AS openingbalance,
    CASE 
       WHEN b.Balance > r.Max_Range
          THEN r.Max_Range - r.Min_Range
          ELSE b.Balance - r.Min_Range
    END AS Split_Balance,
    (CASE 
        WHEN b.Balance > r.Max_Range THEN r.Max_Range - r.Min_Range
        ELSE b.Balance - r.Min_Range
     END) / balance AS weighted_Avg
FROM 
    [EDH_DM_PRD].[dbo].[DataMart_Deposit] AS b
JOIN 
    [DBStats].[dbo].[Split_balances] AS r ON b.Product_Code = r.Product_Code 
                                          AND b.Channel_Desc = r.Channel_Desc
                                          AND b.Asat_Dt = '20190131'
                                          AND b.Acct_Status_Desc  = 'Open'
                                          AND b.Balance >= 0 
                                          AND b.Product_Code = '2000-0100'
                                          AND b.Channel_Desc = 'Broker BDMs'
                                          AND b.Account_Id = '31179111'
ORDER BY 
    Account_Id, Channel_Desc, Min_Range
```

This SQL query returns this result set:

```
| Product_Code | Account_Id | Channel_Desc | Min_Range | Max_Range       | openingbalance | Split_Balance | weighted_Avg           |
| 2000-0100    | 31179111   | Broker BDMs  | 0.000     | 4999.990        | 122314.480     | 4999.990      | 0.04087815277471645221 |
| 2000-0100    | 31179111   | Broker BDMs  | 5000.000  | 9999.990        | 122314.480     | 4999.990      | 0.04087815277471645221 |
| 2000-0100    | 31179111   | Broker BDMs  | 10000.000 | 19999.990       | 122314.480     | 9999.990      | 0.08175638730590196679 |
| 2000-0100    | 31179111   | Broker BDMs  | 20000.000 | 49999.990       | 122314.480     | 29999.990     | 0.24526932543064402513 |
| 2000-0100    | 31179111   | Broker BDMs  | 50000.000 | 99999999999.990 | 122314.480     | 72314.480     | 0.59121765468814485414 |
```

In the resultset "openingbalance" should be specified only on first row.
The remaining rows should show "openbalance" as 0.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what RDBMS you use, but you need `CASE WHEN 1 == ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...) THEN b.Balance ELSE 0 END` or whatever equivalent your DB supports.

To determine what exactly goes into the OVER clause you have to specify more clearly what is the "first" row. If you mean the first row literally you can just use `OVER (ORDER BY Account_Id,Channel_Desc,Min_Range)`, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Hi Nickolay,I am using SQL SERVER 2016.

Comment: @BARG In that case ROW_NUMBER will work ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)), the question is then which "first" row(s) you need. You should change ORDER BY and likely add a PARTITION BY based on that.

Comment: Hi Nicholai,I tried to use     ,case when 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY account_id )
       then b.Balance
       else 0
       end as openingbalance    But except the first row all the other rows are becoming 0. how can i group based on a column?

Comment: Given that you have rows with the same account_id, defining the "first row" as "the first row when sorted by account_id" is not going to work well: any of the rows with the smallest account_id can happen to be the first by that definition.

Comment: "except the first row all the other rows are becoming 0" is exactly what you asked for in the question. I'm not sure I understand "group based on a column". If you want to identify the first row (ordered by X) in each group (identified by Y) you can use `partition by Y order by X`. Did you try to read through the docs or any of the other explanations on the 'net?

Comment: Just for reference i gave AND b.Account_Id = '31179111'.But as per my requirement i have i dont give this statement.So basically for each account 1st row should have a value and the other rows for that account should be 0. the same geos to other account numbers

Comment: So you need to `partition by account_id` and pick a proper `order by`...